# Call nunjucks template macro using variable name

Tags: javascript, nunjucks

Given a macro:

```
{% macro foo() %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Is there a way to call it using a variable name:

```
{% set fn = 'foo' %}
... call macro using 'fn'
```

Alternatively how can I call a macro from a custom tag? I have created a tag that can accept these variables but not sure how to insert a macro from there.

Answer (score 6):

The simple way to do this is use current `context`

```
let env = nunjucks.configure([
...
env.addGlobal('getContext', function(name) { 
    return (name) ? this.ctx[name] : this.ctx;
})
```

In template

```
{% macro foo (arg1, arg2) %}
    {{arg1}}{{arg2}}
{% endmacro %}

{% set fn = 'foo' %}
{{ getContext(fn)(arg1, arg2) }}
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer - it works as op requires

Comment: Brilliant answer: was able to use this technique in the context of 11ty using `addNunjucksGlobal`. Great help.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I have an answer to this. I've been working on this very problem, and have it sort-of working. Maybe you can take what I propose here and expand on it.

The basic premise is to hand-off the rendering to another macro, like so:

```
{% macro eval(fn,data) %}
  {{ fn(data) }}
{% endmacro %}
```

Then:

```
{% set fn = foo %}
{% set data = { this: that } %}
{{ eval(fn,data) }}
```

What I haven't figured out yet is how to evaluate a variable passed into the template from an external source.